# How to show progress dialog when i move from one page to another using jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am developing an app using jquery mobile..
In that i want to show something like progress dialog from one page to another.

I have tried

```
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
```

but it takes a specific amount of time while showing...

Actually my other page loads few graphs so it takes time...
How can we show progress as soon as the graph loads on the other page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You can make use of the events like **pagebeforecreate or pagecreatelike**
And *placing the $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg() in proper place in the code can place major thing.*

```
$('#aboutPage').live('pagebeforecreate',function(event){
  alert('This page was just inserted into the dom!');
});  
$('#aboutPage').live('pagecreate',function(event){
  alert('This page was just enhanced by jQuery Mobile!');
});
```

You can go though the follwing like :
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/#docs/api/events.html

Answer (score 0):

Surround it in

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... }
```

if you aren't already

Answer (score 0):

If you use AJAX to switch between pages you can do the following:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function() {
     $('#loadingDiv').show()
  },
  complete: function(){
     $('#loadingDiv').hide()
  },
  success: function() {}
});
```

"loadingDiv" is your container with spinner gif image (for example).